# React Native Brownfield: two RTCRootView on one screen depend on same API call

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

In the documentation of `RTCRootView`, I see the it is a subclass of `UIView` for iOS. The documentation description says the the `RTCRootView` is a `"Native view used to host React-managed views within the app. Can be used just like any ordinary UIView. You can have multiple RCTRootViews on screen at once, all controlled by the same JavaScript application."`

If I have two React Native components, or two RCTRootViews on one screen but they both depend on an initial API call to render, what is the best way to share this state rather than having two separate JS states making the same API call?

What if this API call is currently wrapped up in Redux state?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both your React Native components are connected to the same redux store, then one one API call should suffice.

Your API call mutates your store state. Both React Native components should receive the new state through new props and react accordingly.

It shouldn't matter that you have two RCTRootView, as long as your *bridge* has been shared correctly between all your RCTRootView.